# Adding jitter to a constrained camera

Tags: rendering, scripting, camera, scene

I am trying to add some camera jitter to my scene. The camera is parented to an empty and constrained to follow a circular path. I tried using the graph editor to add a noise modifier on the Z axis, but that didn't do anything. Is there another procedural way to add the jitter. I even tried to get the target cube to to move up and down. Still no luck.
[image]

Here is my example scene.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. keyframe location on frame 1 for your camera
2. delete x and y location in graph editor:

[image]

3. select z location and add noise modifier
4. change settings to your preferences:

[image]

enjoy!

[image]

[image]

of course you can also add jitter to x and y location if you want to!

Comment: I followed your steps, and looked at the Blend file you posted, but I can't duplicate it. Here is my updated file. What am I doing wrong?                                                                           [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NOpn8l2N" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NOpn8l2N/)

Comment: Never mind. I was adding rotation not location. When I changed to location everything worked.

Comment: A lot would find your answer useful @Chris.

Comment: @Edgel3D : thank you. But it is no rocket science 

Comment: Hi @Chris.  The comment was placed and the answer upvoted because it's often the basic stuff and 'simple tricks' that can count for those who aren't all that savvy.  i.e. it's useful. Camera shake to name just one.

Comment: I appreciated your comment and I understand that and mine wasn’t meant to be negative…☺️